# Is there a single word to describe a "young wizard"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A wizard is an expert magician but there are some trainees (like Sabrina the Teenage Witch). I was wondering if there is a single word to describe an amateur or young wizard as opposed to fully describing as "young wizard".

Comment: I think that generally you would class someone like that as a "Wizard's Apprentice".

Comment: @Hellion so, what about "Wizentice"

Comment: see also: [Wizzard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rincewind)

Comment: In Nethack it would be *Evoker*.

Comment: Does 'novitiate' work?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Rincewind is more of a negative character, not being successful, any positive term?

Comment: @Mitch: You mean, 'Novitiate Wizard'?

Comment: @Gunner [Potter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter) then, maybe? But seriously, I doubt there is a single canon word for this. Though unless Jedi are involved for confusion, I like the sound of [Padawan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padawan#Padawan)

Comment: a little off-the-mark, I guess, but I think should be at least mentioned (if only to be dismissed) in this context: "whiz kid".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since wizard and witch are not typical identities or avocations, at least in the modern English-speaking world, I don't think there is any common term for a newcomer trainee like *resident* or *postulant* or *rookie*.

There may be invented terms specific to various fictional fantasy universes, but in general communication one can expect "wizard" or its equivalent mated with the general terms for newcomers like *novice*, *neophyte*, *trainee*, *fledgling*, *recruit*, and so on, as in *The Sorcerer's Apprentice*.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't be sure that a wizard is necessarily an *expert* magician.

As far as I can tell, there are three main stages in the development of the word "wizard".

1. Its archaic use, meaning a wise man - no explicit supernatural overtones, except that belief in the supernatural was pretty much universal in the middle ages.
2. Its later use, popularised in Tolkien-esque fantasy literature, as a practitioner of sorcery - whether an expert or not; I'm not so sure.
3. Its subsequent use meaning "so expert, it looks like magic"

If there were a specific word for a trainee sorcerer, I would expect to find it widely used in the annals of fantasy fiction, and I have not encountered any such word there.

Comment: Agreed. OP seems to be conflating the modern usage ("expert") with earlier usages which really only exist in fantasy tales now. Obviously if there *were* a standard word for "junior wizard" everyone would already know it, given the ubiquitous Harry Potter books and films.